# Windows installer GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I want to install GeoServer on my windows machine for some testing.
I cannot find the installer anymore:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/win_installer.html

"Warning
Sadly we currently are unable to produce Windows Installers. However we’ve created an instruction on this site to create the installation youself. "
The link with the instructions is not working:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/developer/win-installer.html

Any idea?
Thank you
Francesco

Comment: there is a typo in the link. Luckily the page can be found from the doc main page... try this one https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/win-installer.html

Comment: I've fixed the typo on that page, should be refreshed shortly